# How can a mock's class not equal its java class in Kotlin?

Tags: mockito, kotlin

```
(activity as HomeActivity).javaClass == HomeActivity::class.java
```

Returns `false`. Why? Note, `activity` is mocked with the following function

```
fun set(activity: KClass<out Activity>) {
    this.activity = Mockito.mock(activity.java)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use:

`if(activity is HomeActivity)` instead `(activity as HomeActivity).javaClass == HomeActivity::class.java`

The reason is `Mockito.mock(HomeActivity.java)` will dynamically create a class which *implements* `HomeActivity` using  `SomeFooMockitoImpl.class` which gets `HomeActivity.class` as parameter to create that mocked instance.

You can check in runtime mock object will be something like:
`HomeActivity$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b8254f54`

and its actual class name by:

`activity.javaClass.simpleName` (should be `SomeFooMockitoImpl`)

Comment: yup the runtime mock object looks like that. Btw, `HomeActivity` is a class, not an interface

Comment: Yep. I meant the mock objected returned by mockito is a class which implements HomeActivity.

Comment: how would you fix this test so it passes then?

Comment: `if(activity is HomeActivity)` should be enough